# How to see unit test integration result of non-maven java project in sonar

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube, jacoco

How can see unit test integration result of non-maven java project in sonar. I have the latest version of Sonar installed and have latest java plugin. I think this java plugin comes along with jacaco and surefire. I used sonar-runner to analyse my project.

How can I run jacoco with my non maven java project and integrate the result with sonar.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following example to see how to get coverage result with JaCoCo and SonaQube runner: https://github.com/bellingard/multi-language-test

More specifically, look into the `sonar-project.properties` file and this section:

```
# For Java
sonar.junit.reportsPath=reports/java/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=reports/java/jacoco.exec
sonar.binaries=target/classes
```